# How can i fix this error message saying "failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase'" when i try to create an android app through cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-2.0.0

I have added firebase plugin to cordova for push notification. When I try to create android app using command "cordova platform add android" I am getting error message saying failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase' and can any one please suggest me how can i fix this issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your android version. This solved for me.

```
cordova platform

cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@version_number
```